# I generated barcode image to picture box and then wrote to printing. Is there any method to write generated image directly to print document?

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, printdocument

I have generated barcode image and loaded to picture box and then I wrote it to print document. Is there any method to write generated image directly to print document?

**My code is :**

```
// Code to generate barcode image


private void btnGen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("3x2 Inc", 300, 200);
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };
writer.Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions { Width = 250, Height = 100, Margin = 0 };
pbBar.Width = 250; // pbBar is my picture box.
pbBar.Height = 100;
pbBar.Image = writer.Write(txtCode.Text);
}

// Print document code

private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
Bitmap map = new Bitmap(pbBar.Width, pbBar.Height);
pbBar.DrawToBitmap(map, new Rectangle(0, 0, pbBar.Width, pbBar.Height));
gr.DrawImage(map, 20, 40);
}
```

Comment: Add a Bitmap Field to the Form class (e.g., `private Bitmap currentBarCode = null;`), set it with `currentBarCode = writer.Write(txtCode.Text);`, show it: `pbBar.Image = currentBarCode;`, print it: `e.Graphics.DrawImage(currentBarCode, 20, 40);` (maybe use an overload of `DrawImage()` to specify a destination Rectangle, if needed)

Answer (score 0):

`writer.Write` returns `BitMap` you can directly use that

```
private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };
    writer.Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions { Width = 250, Height = 100, Margin = 0 };    
    Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
    gr.DrawImage(writer.Write(txtCode.Text), 20, 40);
}
```

Comment: Do be careful with `Bitmap` class though; if you're not using them in a `using` block, these objects need to be disposed explicitly when you're done with them.